# How to resolve setBackgroundDrawable being deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, background, drawable

On Android Studio it keeps saying that `setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated as well as `getWidth` and `getHeight`.

How do I solve this?

```
ivImage.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply read the documentation of the function and do what they tell you. For
`ImageView.setBackgroundDrawable`, the documentation tells you to use `setBackground`:

> public void setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable background)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 16. use setBackground(Drawable) instead

For `getWidth` and `getHeight` on `Display` the documentation tells you to do this:

> public int getWidth ()
>   Added in API level 1
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use getSize(Point) instead.

This comes down to

```
Point point = null;
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
int width = point.x;
int height = point.y;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);` with `.setBackground(gd);`

this will most probably solve your issue

```
ivImage.setBackground(gd);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got a resource id then we can use `setBackgroundResource()` which is  **API level 1**.

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```

As per the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29),`setBackground()`just calls `setBackgroundDrawable()`

```
 public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
  }

@Deprecated 
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) { ... }
```